# Outlook search folder for email that is X minutes old?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, search-folder

Is there any way to create a search folder in Outlook that lists email that is X minutes old? The earliest I see is 1 Day old in Outlook 2010, but I can go to Advanced and select:

```
Field        Condition         Value
-------------------------------------------
Received     "on or before"    ????
```

I'm not sure what to place for the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying a single search you can do: `2:00pm today` (or whatever your time block is).

For a time based approach you can search in advanced find for `recieved` `on or after` `5 min ago` ... `hours ago` is also supported.

Comment: I couldn't get your `now()-1h` function to work for me.  Can you elaborate on the steps you took to do that?  Or was it just a suggestion that it _might_ work

Comment: I can elaborate when I'm back at a computer :) Did the single search syntax (time based) work out for you?

Comment: I updated my answer, the function works - but is unreliable.

Comment: +1 That worked for me now.  Of course, I wasn't the one who asked, but I found it cool nonetheless.